# How long it can take to insert record in coredata?

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I'm inserting records in my core data entities.
As records getting increase its taking time to insert records.

**I have log of 6 seconds to insert 100 records(for loop to insert one by one) when my entity has around 10000 records.**

What I'm doing is checking while inserting that if that record already exists then I'm updating that record else inserting.

Every iteration of a loop has information of 14 relational table.

So it this okay? or 6 second is much more?

Comment: You are probably using different contexts to write and read and go for a wrong approach to merge the changes inbetween the contexts. Post code to have a chance to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

No it is too long.  You are doing it wrong.  But there is a better way!  Do a single fetch fetch for all of the records you want to insert first.  Then store them in a dictionary by the lookup key that you are making sure is unique (probably an ID of some sort).  Then instead of doing a fetch for every insert you just check the dictionary.  If you have a lot of relationships and in your create and/or update methods are doing fetches (to insure uniqueness) the amount of fetches can quickly get out of hand.  You can solve this by passing along your lookup dictionary so that more fetches do not have to be done.  Of course you have to be careful to not pass these dictionary to thread that are not related to the managedObjectContext that the fetch was done on.

Comment: hmm, Yes debugging code to identify which part of the code is taking time

Comment: 2017-02-20 19:10:27.254 CFBundleDisplayName[41438:1981146] Inserting Records
2017-02-20 19:10:34.807 CFBundleDisplayName[41438:1981146] DB Updated